# Async behavior in C# IIS and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, multithreading, asynchronous

I have some questions regarding my usage of async - await functionality particularly in ADO.NET.

If I understand correctly, the correct usage will allow my web server to be more responsive to incoming requests because the threads will no longer be sitting around waiting for the e.g. SQL Server query to finish its work. I can get full async behavior right down to the ADO.NET data reader through the asyn API there.

My question is that if my primary load before going async was the database would it be far fetched to assume that because there are now more free threads to handle incoming requests, these requests would put more strain to my database than before?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have more requests to handle - yes. But this would mean the database was overloaded and requests were piling up waiting.

Assuming your database did cope with the load (which does not magically increase just because you ue async) then obviously not. You just need less front end servers now ;)